# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE "INSTITUTION" (  
    "institution_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,                 
    "institution_name" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
    "institution_address" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,                 
    "institution_phoneNumber" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,                 
    "institution_website" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE,                 
    "institution_email" VARCHAR2(80) ENABLE,                 
    "institution_fax" VARCHAR2(20) ENABLE,                 
    "institution_workingHrs" VARCHAR2(50) ENABLE,                 
    "institution_workingDays" VARCHAR2(50) ENABLE,                 
    "inst_location_code" VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL ENABLE,                 
    "inst_category_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,                 
    "mimetype" VARCHAR2(50) ENABLE,                                        
    "filename" VARCHAR2(60) ENABLE,                 
    "institution_image" BLOB ENABLE,                 
    CONSTRAINT "INSTITUTION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("institution_ID") ENABLE
)
```

I get

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

when running this code in Apex. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The ENABLE keyword only goes after a constraint, like NOT NULL. But you have it after all of your columns.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it